# Combining "column-count" and "display: table" renders single column in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to work out an issue in Firefox (I'm using 40.0.3) where using `-moz-column-count` and `display: table` causes a list to display as one column. Here's my example and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/094gmjp2/1/):

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>cdefg</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using `display: table` to center the columns in the div. In Edge, IE10 and Chrome the list is in two columns.

My question is how can I get two columns with `display: table` in Firefox or how to properly center the list so that it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, I think Chrome and IE are the ones being wrong. They ***do*** give what you want, but they ***should not***, like FF.

In your code you 'say' **`split-div-in-2-columns`** but essentially you put in only one ***ul***. When you split your ***ul*** in two (see snippet) then FF works as expected, as do CH and IE BTW.

If I had created your code I actually **would** expect only one column, namely an ul of li's (or one div of p's, one p of span's, etc.). A second ul would be the second column (a second div..., etc.). Hence my conclusion that Chrome and IE mess up.

I hate unexpected behaviour like this, makes one unsure which browser is correct.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2; /* demo code */
}
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>cdefg</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**-  Update with extra demo code -**

In addition some demo snippet how you could use it without a `table`. Simply take **your** code remove the table stuff and move the `column-count` to the ***ul***.

That works just as well:

```css
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none; padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 500px; /* just some width */
    border: 2px dashed silver;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center in body */
}
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center in div */
}

li {
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>cdefg</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good one Rene! Deserves the bounty.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar I never seize to be amazed about the huge number of inconsistencies between browsers and bugs after 20 years (and over) of browser technology. I am an ol'school (pre-windows, pre-DOS even) software engineer and I think especially MS should be deeply ashamed.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar forgot a proper thankyou, so, thank you for the compliment. But I am not really after the bounty, to me it's more a sign that there are pressing issues left open. BTW, is there a way to communicate with ppl directly (besides chat). I am looking for a graph designer/tech to build a smart, simplified CSS frame with the least Vanilla JS (opensource). Interested?

Comment: Thanks for your invite. Wish I could join you, but I am not sure if I can work on it currently. I would be glad to see what you are trying to build though. Send me an email: me@manojkr.com

Comment: Thanks for your input Rene. I'm not usually a web dev and now that I look at it more it makes sense that FF would put it in one column

Answer (score 7):

> How to properly center the list so that it works in all browsers?

You can use CSS3 flexible box layout to center align the list. Since you are using CSS3 multi-column layout, I assume you are building the list for modern browsers. Thus the [**flexible box**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) approach is the way to go.

1. Let the `<div>` be the flexible items container. `justify-content:center` will align the list to the center.
2. Set the column count on
   the `<ul>`. You can set the `*-column-gap` for the spacing between
   the columns.

Works on Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge and Opera ( *i.e. basically all browsers* ). Here is a [**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/gc8coeLq/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 100px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 100px;
  column-gap: 100px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2> Centered CSS3 multi-column layout </h2>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>cdefg</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are centering `div` with minimal width in the container, but in the question he centers `li`s inside of each column.

Comment: Maybe you are right here, but I took this *I'm using display: table to **center the columns in the div***. This demo is based on assuming he only wants to center the columns and not the items inside. So I have to wait for OP's response here for improvising the answer.

Comment: The OP accepted the answer (which does the job, evidently) just before I posted mine. While correct, this solution hides the problem that, again, there is a browser quirk that needs working around. See my answer and please do comment on it, I'd like to hear your ideas about this.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `display:block` on ul because column-count don't work properly with `display:table` in Firefox.

You can use `width: fit-content;` to center the columns in the div.

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>cdefg</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `fit-content` has a bad browser support.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to check for Firefox using `@supports` rule.
As the other browsers don't support `-moz-column-count` they are not affected.
And FF can get individual solution inside of that block.

https://jsfiddle.net/094gmjp2/5/

```css
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@supports (-moz-column-count: 2) {
    ul {
        display: block;
        width: -moz-fit-content;
        width: fit-content;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>asadf</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>cadsfa</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```